# Can't boot into safe mode

Tags: startup, safe-mode

I have an older 2009? 27” iMac. Doing a OS update has given me the error “macOS could not be installed on your computer. An error occurred while updating firmware…”
So, attempting to boot in safe mode, I turn on, holding down the shift key. After a few seconds, it reboots, and continues to reboot every 6-8 seconds, never attempting to start. If I let off the shift key it starts only to ultimately bring me back to the macOS error message. I have files I really want to save, so reformatting is not a preferred option. Any ideas on how to get into safe mode? Or fix the error?

Comment: That’s a boot loop and it sounds like the OS didn’t get installed alright.  I would try reinstalling the MacOS system again.

Comment: Can you get to Recovery? [Cmd/R at the chimes]. If so, try reinstalling the OS from there - it should leave all your data intact.

Comment: So, you guys are right. I was able to reinstall from the recovery area and all my data is in tact. Thank you for great advice!